# How to calculate the total value of a dynamic number of fields using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My page shows some forms with content loaded from a database. Every row will get his own `<input>`. The ID of this input is equal for every row, except for the number that is attached to it, to make it unique. To make it more clear; this is how the form looks like when it loads 3 rows from the database:

```
<form>
<input id="Amount1" value="<?php echo $databaseValue; ?>" >
<input id="Amount2" value="<?php echo $databaseValue; ?>" >
<input id="Amount3" value="<?php echo $databaseValue; ?>" >
<input type="hidden" name="numberOfRows">
<input id="finalResult">
</form>
```

This is all done with the `mysqli_array` function. The value of `numberOfRows` is based on `numRows` function.

What I'd like to achieve is that javascript calculates the value of each existing input and put the result in `finalResult`, regardless the number of forms (because this may vary). If I make some changes to one of the values, the finalResult should update real-time.

What I've tried so far:

`formnum` contains the number of fields.

`var a` is created at the beginning, starting at 0. Inside it's function I create an ID, matching the fields on the page. All fields are named "Amount" + number. If this number equals the number of fields, the function will stop. This way the script won't be looking for fields that doesn't excist.

Then it gets the value of this field and adds the value to `var b`. `var b` is just created to store the value temporary, untill the function's over.

At the end the total is divided to 15. This is something extra I need. Nothing special on this line.

My code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
          var formnum = $("#numberOfRows").val();
          var a;
          var b = 0;
          var formname = '#Amount';

          for (a = 0; a < formnum; a++) {
              var complete = formname.concat(a);
              var completeContent = $(complete).val();

              b = b + completeContent;
            };

          b = b.toFixed(2);
});

$(document).mousemove(function(event){
          var formula_finalResult = b / 15;
          var total_finalResult = Math.floor(formula_finalResult);

          $("#finalResult").val(total_finalResult);
});

</script>
```

This doesn't do anything. It doesn't change the value. What's going wrong?

Comment: Does the value total_finalResult is getting updated correctly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33987539/adding-numbers-and-create-a-div-for-the-result/33987600#33987600

Comment: I'm not sure, because the function's closed before the formula_finalResult call's to it again. I'm not sure if formula_finalResult knows what b is. But I don't know how to change this in order to update all values real-time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it simple:

```
$(function(){
   var sum = 0;
   // Selector to select all input whose id starts with Amount
   $("input[id*='Amount']").each(function(){

        sum += +$(this).val(); // Parsing as int and adding it to sum

   });
   $("#finalResult").val(Math.floor(sum/15)); // Storing the values
})
```

Comment: I've changed the function of your code to mousemove event to update it realtime. Now it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all of the fields always have `Amount` at the beginning of their `id` attribute, you could use jQuery's ID selector to achieve this, without the need for any of the internal counters, etc.

I'm not entirely sure why you need to hook into the `mousemove` event, since the data should never change on the page (since it's being generated by PHP when the page is first loaded). The following code should achieve what you're looking for:

```
$(function() {

    var total = 0;

    $('input[id*="Amount"]').each(function() { total+= parseFloat( $(this).val() ); });

    $('#finalResult').val( Math.floor( total / 15 ) );

});
```

Comment: I use the mousemove event to update the result real-time. The final result will be stored as value in an input tag. I need the total before I press submit.

Comment: But in your question, `b` is never modified after the initial DOM load, so the value set inside of your `mousemove` handler will always be the same?

Comment: Yes, I see. You're right. Missed that error. Let's see if that makes the difference.

Comment: I've changed the function of your code to mousemove event to update it realtime. Now it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to change the generated Html-Source I would suggest to give a new class to your InputElements.

```
<input id="Amount1" class="ElementToCount" value="<?php echo $databaseValue; ?>" >
```

Then you can calculate like that

```
var getSumOfElements = function() {
    var Elements = $('.ElementToCount')
    var sum=0
    if (Elements && Elements.length>0) {
        for (var i=0; i<Elements.length; i++) {
           sum += Elements[i].val();
        }
    }
    return sum
}
```

And to update the field you could register to the 'change'-Event

```
$('.ElementToCount).on('change', function() {
    $('#finalResult').val(getSumOfElements());
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: b is not defined`
see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/ca9vascj/

There's no reason to bring the `mousemove` event into this, I'm not even sure what that was needed for.

Like the above answers, here's a much simplified version.  But instead of a partial ID selection, let's just give the form an ID, and then give all the needed elements inside that form a class that we can select by.  We also no longer need to have the `numberOfRows` form element.

```
<form id="theForm">
    <input class="formAmmount" value="5" />
    <input class="formAmmount" value="10" />
    <input class="formAmmount" value="27.5" />
    <input class="formAmmount" value="4" />
    <input class="formAmmount" value="9" />

    <hr />

    <input id="finalResult" />
</form>
```

And then our jQuery code can be reduced to this:

```
$(function(){
    var total = 0;
    $("#theForm .formAmmount").each(function(){
        total += parseFloat(this.value, 10);
    });
    var final = Math.floor(total.toFixed(2) / 15);
    $("#finalResult").val(final);
});
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/ca9vascj/1/

Answer (score 0):

You dont'need jQuery. The simplest way to do this is `document.getElementsByTagName`:

```
var inputs = document.getElementById('my-form').getElementsByTagName('input')
```

That's it. `inputs.length` will always get an actual count of inputs in your form. That's because `getElementsByTagName()` returns a NodeList object, containing a live view of the matching elements. This object is mutable; it will change in response to DOM mutations.

So if you need to get sum from all of the inputs:

```
function sum() {
   var result = 0;
   [].slice.call(inputs).forEach(function(input){
       result += parseFloat(input.value)
   });
   return result; 
}
```